# Why does "res.send" giving me an older version of a Mongoose document?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have an express API endpoint that deletes a Post. I have attached a mongoose pre-hook that, in turn, deletes also references to the `Comment` model and references from the User model:

```
PostSchema.pre("remove", async function() {
  await Comment.remove({ _postId: this._id }).exec();
  await User.update({ $pull: { _posts: this._id } }).exec();
});
```

This hook successfully removes all references to/from `Comment` and `User` models when the `Post` is removed. However, when I send the User model back to the user as a response (`res.send(user)`), I am still getting the reference to the `Post`. I know it's an older version that is being sent because when I manually query the database, I see that the `Post` reference was actually removed.

This is how the API looks like:

```
  app.delete(
    "/api/posts/:postId",
    requireAuth,
    async (req, res, next) => {
      try {
        const post = await Post.findById(req.params.postId);
        if (post._userId.equals(req.user._id)) {
          await post.remove();
          const user = await req.user.save();
          res.send(req.user);
        } else {
          res.send("Error:", "This post does not belong to you");
        }
      } catch (err) {
        next(err);
      }
    }
  );
```

(Note that `requireAuth` is a middleware that uses passportjs to get the jwt and deserialize the user)

Comment: Did you try to do console.log(user) after `req.user.save()` to see if user is updated or not ? I wanna know if it gets updated

Comment: `const user = await req.user.save();` what are you saving and why?

Comment: @Artur answer is usually the best approach. To elaborate on your question, usually but not in all cases, every `DbContext`, by removing the post from user, it doesnt actually removes/deletes the `entity` data from the `context` object, instead it flags it as `deleted`. It does that so it will have all the necessary metadata to do the deletion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In `requireAuth` you get User from database and store it in req.user
2. `await post.remove();` you removed Post and Post reference from User, all ok
3. `const user = await req.user.save();` - You are saving old User (grabbed from no1.) to database. Not good. You must update User object stored in req.user before any other action. req.user still store old version of User.

In my opinion instead of

```
const user = await req.user.save();
```

You should get fresh user from database (find), assign fresh user to req.user and finaly pass it to res.send(user)

```
  app.delete(
    "/api/posts/:postId",
    requireAuth,
    async (req, res, next) => {
      try {
        const post = await Post.findById(req.params.postId);
        if (post._userId.equals(req.user._id)) {
          await post.remove();
          const user = await User.findById(req.user._id).exec();
          req.user = user;
          res.send(req.user);
        } else {
          res.send("Error:", "This post does not belong to you");
        }
      } catch (err) {
        next(err);
      }
    }
  );
```

Comment: is `.exec()` necessary when refreshing the `User` from the database?

Comment: Yes. funct. Model.findById() by default returns Query instead of Promise, so 
It will not work with async await func (which works with Promises only). http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyid_findById

Comment: then I have to use same approach for `const post = await Post.findById(req.params.postId);`  - Thanks for clarification

Comment: Yes, I haven't noticed this before :)

Comment: One more disclaimer I remember: when you use Bluebird instead of mongoose native Promise this behawior with .exec(), is quite different. From my practice, when i used Bluebird promises, exec() at the end it was not necesary, this is quite complicated

Comment: that explains why it works with or without `.exec()`